# Can Slippers of Spider Climbing be used to stick to the ground?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

If a giant bird that can pick people up comes at me and I activate my Slippers of Spider Climbing while standing on the ground, will this hinder or even prevent the bird from picking me up?

Is it reasonable to assume that whatever allows me to walk on walls and ceilings while resisting the pull of gravity gives me an attachment to surfaces equal to the pull of gravity, and thus the bird would have to overcome essentially double the gravity?

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPG.SE!  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] page for information on how things work around here.  The first part of your question is a good one but the second part is highly opinion-based ("What do you think would be...?").  Opinion based questions don't work very well in this format because they are highly subjective and no one has a way of identifying what answer is the best.  I've removed that second question as it adds no value here.

Comment: A [search for spider climb](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22spider+climb%22) brings up many related questions that you might find useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing in the item's description that indicates the slippers are at all sticky or would otherwise keep you "stuck" to the ground.

> When worn, a pair of these slippers **enables movement on vertical
>   surfaces or even upside down along ceilings**, leaving the wearer's
>   hands free. Her climb speed is 20 feet. Severely slippery surfaces—icy, oiled, or greased surfaces—make these slippers useless.

The only mechanical effect or advantage this magic item provides is hands-free climbing and a 20ft climb speed.

As for the second part of your question, would you reasonably assume that a spider clinging to a wall is somehow more stuck to the wall than he would be to the ground?  I'm not sure how gravity is involved at all, and it's best not to bring physics into game rules because when you do, everything begins falling apart. The item grants ability to climb without using your hands and grants you a climb speed of 20' -- nothing more.

Anything beyond the description of the item is something you need to discuss with your GM.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you had incredible abs and other muscles, just the soles of your feet sticking to a wall would not be entirely beneficial.  My ruling has been that it reorients gravity as it pertains you you and your gear.  So your feet are not stuck to the wall or ceiling any more than they would be if you were standing on the ground normally.